# Bandwidth on multiport Network Card

Tags: networking, port

When a 1Gb Network Card has two ports, the bandwith on each Port is :

**Case 1** :
Port 1 = 1 Gb
Port 2 = 1 Gb

**Case 2 :** 
Port 1 = 1/2 Gb
Port 2 = 1/2 Gb

**Case 3 :** 
Port 1 = < 1 Gb & > 1/2 Gb
Port 2 = < 1 Gb & > 1/2 Gb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test? Too lazy do read specs?

1. Every port is independent and it is acutally SOLD AS A FULL PORT, so 2 and 3 would be product fraud.

The whole sense of buying am multi port card is to have multiple FULL ports.